# Does overflow:hidden do clear:

Tags: html, css

In one post I read there was a question about floated `<li>` in `<ul>`. The guy was asking why his `<ul>` background disappears when he floated the `<li>`'s and how he could fix this. An answer was to set `overflow:hidden` to the `<ul>`. I tried it, and it will worked, but I haven't read and heard before something like that.

My question is: Can you use `overflow:hidden` for clearing elements like clearfix?

In this case:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

if I have the following CSS:

```
ul{
  background: #999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
```

Do I still need to clear with: `<ul class="clearfix">` and CSS:

```
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
.clearfix:after { 
    width: 100%; 
    content: ''; 
    font-size: 0; 
    line-height: 0; 
    text-indent: -4000px; 
    clear: both; 
    display:block; 
}
```

Or I just can let `overflow:hidden` to do that job

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes!

There are three ways to `clear`:

1. Using `overflow: hidden;` to the parent of the `float`ed elements.
2. Giving a `float: left;` or `float: right;` to the parent of the `float`ed elements.
3. Giving a `clear`ing element as a sibling at the end of the floated elements.

#### For your question...

Yes, you can just use the `overflow: hidden;` to do, but there's a problem. Say you have something like flyout list or popover, those things get cut with the dimensions of the `UL` tag.

If you want them to be displayed too, you need to use `<ul class="clearfix">`. I would say, `clearfix` is better than `overflow: hidden;`.

*ps: I am a front end engineer developing enterprise web applications that compatible across all browsers.*

Comment: Also please check out: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html and http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/